# Group message issues with iPhone users

Tags: sms

I just switched from an iPhone 5S just two days ago and now using LG G3.

I am having trouble with group messages. As an example, let's say there are four users in a group chat, 1 Android, 3 iPhones. It seems that if I'm participating in the group chat, all the iPhone users can see my messages, but I cannot see reply messages. After some testing, it seems that if an iPhone initiates the group chat, I will be able to see their messages, only theirs (and not the others).

I have MMS enabled. I have also tried some third party apps (Google Hangouts, Textra, but to no avail).

Lastly, I use SPRINT. What network mode should I be in (Global, LTE/CDMA, CDMA, GSM/UMTS)? Currently, I am on Global, which was the default. My house is in an area with dodgy phone connection for sprint, but I spend most of my time where there is a decent connection (3G, I believe).

Comment: This question is quite old but you need to essentially deactivate iMessage.  There are guides online.